# Zoo Flexible Admin

Tags: zoo

If i am logged into the control panel via "system" and create a menu and save it in zoo flex admin, it can only be used if you login via "system" and not admin.php

If you do use admin.php and click the links you get a 404, and vice versa if you create them when logged in via /admin.php

Anyone have any ideas how i can use both?